# Does C# feature a #include equivalent for #def constants?

Tags: c#, c

Before people tear this question apart, I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

I currently have a C program that has access to shared memory. The C program navigates this shared memory via #defined offsets. Example:

```
#define VAR_1 0x2000
```

Now I have a C# program that displays data from this shared memory. I'm trying to determine how I can use the #defines that my C program uses and let my C# program also reference them.

I'm trying to avoid needing to maintain two files that contain these definitions.

Thus, is there any way for a C# program to use #defines from a .h file?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it possible for the C and C# program to load the offset at runtime? If so, put it in a configuration file and load it at runtime.

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: It is easy to do with C++/CLI, not with C#.  Beyond a config file, you could consider writing these offsets in the MMF, at the start of the view at a well-known location (like 0).  Kinda of the point of shared memory :)

Comment: Since you have sources of c-project, the easiest is to use T4 templates to generate cs-files from h-files, e.g. static classes with constants. You will have to write T4 once and maintain only header file.

Comment: Write a parser for .h files in C#; include it in your C# project, use the .h file as a config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The short answer is no](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-define):

> The `#define` directive cannot be used to declare constant values as
>   is typically done in C and C++. Constants in C# are best defined as
>   static members of a class or struct. If you have several such
>   constants, consider creating a separate "Constants" class to hold
>   them.

You could do something like this:

constants.cs:

```
#if __STDC__
#define public
#else
namespace foo
{
    class Constants {
#endif

public const int VAR_1 = 0x2000;

#if __STDC__
#undef public
#else
    }
}
#endif
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "constants.cs"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", VAR_1);
    return 0;
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
namespace foo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Constants.VAR_1);
        }
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wpedantic main.c && ./a.out 
8192
$ dotnet run
8192
```

This is using `const int` instead of `#define` in C, but that may be a tradeoff that you are willing to make.